# How do I make my ion-input equal width with my ion-item

Tags: css, ionic-framework, layout, ion-item

My `ion-input` element has a grey line spanning the entire width of the view. I want it so the line is 
equal to the `ion-item` elements.

```
    <ion-content padding>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>
            <h1><strong>{{$route.params.excercise}}</strong> working set weight</h1>
            <p>Include bar and plates</p>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-input placeholder="... kg" type="number" min="0" step="1.25"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      ...
```

```
<style scoped>
ion-input {
  width: inherit; // doesn't work
}
</style>
```

Width too wide.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `class="ion-padding"` from https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities and `lines="inset"` or `lines="full"` from https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item

Option 1:

```
 <ion-list class="ion-padding">
      <ion-item lines="full">
        <ion-label>
          <h1><strong>Squat</strong> working set weight</h1>
          <p>Include bar and plates</p>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item lines="full">
        <ion-input placeholder="... kg" type="number" min="0" step="1.25"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Option 2:

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <ion-list>
      <ion-item lines="inset">
        <ion-label>
          <h1><strong>Squat</strong> working set weight</h1>
          <p>Include bar and plates</p>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item lines="inset">
        <ion-input placeholder="... kg" type="number" min="0" step="1.25"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

[image]